# What's going on with CheckStyle's line length check?

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I have CheckStyle set to check for lines over 80 characters in Eclipse, and I have a margin line set up in my editor at 80 characters. If I put my cursor at the end of a line of code in my editor, the co-ordinates read (for example) 1433, 77, indicating the 77th character column from the left - yet when I run CheckStyle over the same line it says the line is 88 characters long! There are no extraneous tabs or other whitespace characters at the end of the line, it's definitely 77 long. Is CheckStyle broken?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Checkstyle documentation:

> The calculation of the length of a line takes into account the number of expanded spaces for a tab character ('\t'). The default number of spaces is 8. To specify a different number of spaces, the user can set TreeWalker property tabWidth which applies to all Checks, including LineLength; or can set property tabWidth for LineLength alone.
>
> http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_sizes.html#LineLength

To do this in Eclipse:

- Open Window->Preferences from the Menu.
- Select *Checkstyle*.
- Type `TreeWalker` into the search box under *Known modules*.
- Select *TreeWalker* on the list on the right.
- Click *Open*.
- Change the *tabWidth* to 4.
- Click *OK*, and *OK* again.

**Note**: in newer versions of Checkstyle setting the tab width is done via a property of `LineLength`, as you can see in the config below (thanks for the hint @dropbear):

```xml
<module name="LineLength">
  <property name="tabWidth" value="2"/>
</module>
```

Comment: To expand on this: Since Checkstyle 8.24 LineLength should be under Checker instead of TreeWalker. If using 8.24 or newer tabWidth specified for TreeWalker (like suggested it can be in this answer and the documentation) is not taken into account, it needs to be specified directly as a property of the LineLength module now.
Changelog: https://checkstyle.org/releasenotes.html#Release_8.24
Issue: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/2116

Answer (score 2):

> Is CheckStyle broken?

Probably not.

I expect you/Eclipse and CheckStyle have a different idea of the width of a TAB character.  It sounds you think it means 4 spaces, whereas CheckStyle thinks it means 8 characters (its default).

One way around this is to configure Eclipse to not use TAB characters in your source file, then re-indent your source files.

Another way is to make use that CheckStyle and Eclipse agree on the TAB width; e.g. see @MartinEllis's answer.

(I prefer the first approach because it means that my source code will look correctly indented, irrespective of the platform's default TAB width; i.e. Windows versus Linux/Unix.  Hard TAB characters in source code are *a bad idea*.)